# Eigenvectors of Kernel Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K\in L^2([a,b]\times[a,b])$, $K(s,t)=\overline K(t,s)$,

define $Tf(s)=\int_a^bK(s,t)\bar f(t)\,dt$ for $f \in L^2([a,b])$

I need to show that the eigenfunctions of $T$ are an orthonormal basis for $L_2([a,b])$

I tried to show $T$ is self-adjoint (**it isn't** because of the conjugate on $f$ in the intergral) and that it is normal - $TT^*=T^*T$ (also doesnt work)

is there another way to show?

Comment: since it's self-adjoint compact its eigenfunctions form a basis of the underlying space

Comment: thats the issue, its not self-adjoint

Comment: What's your definition of the inner product?

Comment: If the inner product is defined by $\displaystyle\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(s)\overline{g(s)} \, ds,$ then you have
$$
\begin{align}
& \langle Tf,g\rangle = \int_a^b (Tf)(s)\overline{g(s)}\, ds = \int_a^b\left( \int_a^b K(s,t) \overline {f(t)} \, dt \right) \overline {g(s)} \, ds \\ {} \\
= {} & \int_a^b \left( \int_a^b K(s,t)\overline{g(s)} \, ds \right) \overline{f(t)} \, dt = \int_a^b (Tg)(t)\overline {f(t)} \, dt \\ {} \\
= {} & \langle Tg,f\rangle = \overline{ \langle f, Tg\rangle}.
\end{align}
$$